# Facebook - how to get public profile image using graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, profile-picture

please help me get new way to get **public** profile picture from FB. I'm using it in my home system to get current user photo.
Few days ago something has changed and my solution stopped working.
I was using graph for 3 pictures:
Example:
https://graph.facebook.com/17xxxxxxx94/picture?type=large
But this is not working anymore. It seems they enabled some security and token is required.

[With app token I created under developers.facebook.com I'm able to get my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krJzp.png)

However only mine, not able to get picture for other users. Is there a way to create some token to get public picture from FB?

Comment: The relevant changes are explained under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/#requirements

Comment: _“not able to get picture for other users”_ - what other users, where did you get their IDs from?

Comment: _“With app token I created under developers.facebook.com I'm able to get my picture”_ - I hope by that you are referring to fetching the image on the server side? The actual app access token (if that is what you are talking about, and not a user token) should never be exposed in publicly available client-side code.

Comment: other users = my FB friends, I was using their unique <fb-user-id>

Comment: So that would be the old, global UID then. I think you would need a user access token from the particular user then. App access tokens don’t work with global UIDs.

Comment: I did not expose that token, I used it locally in my home assistant system to retrieve picture. I'm not developer, so I can't retrieve my friends profile picture anymore?

Comment: No, not this way. You would have to create an app and have your friends login to that first, so that you can then use their access token.

Comment: can each user generate some access token in FB page? I'm not familiar that much with FB.

Comment: They could, but user tokens expire, so they would have to do this regularly. (I don’t think _I_ could be bothered to do that, just so that any friend of mine can display my profile pick in their private home assistant system …) If you’re not a developer, and/or not familiar with the FB API, then I’d say, forget about it, this will get more complex than what that little “feature” is actually worth.

Comment: I agree, it was easy till now. Now it's much more complicated and not worth my time anymore. Thank you!